# PlaybackNearlyFinished and PlaybackFinished occur almost at the same time?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

It turns out, that sometimes (not always btw but very frequently) `PlaybackNearlyFinished` and `PlaybackFinished` occur almost at the same time. What also confuses is that both of the events convey exactly the same offset that represents the very end of the stream:

[image]

When this happens the next stream scheduled in PlaybackNearlyFinished does not go - the playback just finishes.

Unless this is a bug in Alexa/Infrastructure, I can not figure out how to implement a playback for a playlist - there's just no way to reliably schedule the upcoming track...

Is there anything I could do in my code to make it work well?

I am using Echo Dot 2 gen., physically located in Europe, use java SDK, AWS Lambda, Dynamo DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is figured out now - in order to queue the next stream properly one needs to come up with really unique stream tokens. This means that even the same file/url should be enqueued under a unique token.

In my example above, I used the index of the track in the playlist as an token. Once I solved it like below, everything started to work like a charm:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class TokenService {

    public String createToken(int playbackPosition) {
        String suffix = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(16);
        return String.valueOf(playbackPosition) + ":" + suffix;
    }

    public int tokenToPlaybackIndex(String token) {
        String positionStr = token.split(":")[0];
        return Integer.valueOf(positionStr);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps somebody!